# adding user to windows make the administrator icon to disappear !

Tags: windows, user-accounts

I used the command "net user" to add a new admin user to windows like that:

> net user myuser11 myuser11 /add net
>
> localgroup Administrators myuser11 /add

the problem that after restart windows I only see the icon of the "myuser" and the default windows "Administrator" login icon disappeared !!

the "Administrator" files still exists and I can login as "Administrator" after ctrl+alt+del but I need of course to display the "Administrator" icon in welcome screen

how I fix that ?

I use windows xp sp3

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is by design. If you have another user with Administrator rights, Windows doesn't show the "Administrator" login any more.

You can change it in the registry I believe:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList

Then add 'Administrator' to that list as a DWORD value (if it's not there already) and set it's value to 1. It's been a while since I used XP, so that might not be exactly correct, but I think it is...